# Average Date Array Calculation

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy, pandas

I would like to get the mean of the following dates. I thought about converting all the data to seconds and then averaging them. But there is probably a better way to do it.

```
date = ['2016-02-23 09:36:26', '2016-02-24 10:00:32', '2016-02-24 11:28:22', '2016-02-24 11:27:20', '2016-02-24 11:24:15', '2016-02-24 11:20:25', '2016-02-24 11:17:43', '2016-02-24 11:12:03', '2016-02-24 11:09:11', '2016-02-24 11:08:44', '2016-02-24 11:05:28', '2016-02-24 11:03:23', '2016-02-24 10:58:08', '2016-02-24 10:53:59', '2016-02-24 10:49:34', '2016-02-24 10:43:33', '2016-02-24 10:35:27', '2016-02-24 10:31:50', '2016-02-24 10:31:17', '2016-02-24 10:30:05', '2016-02-24 10:29:21']
```

**Nasty solution:**

```
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np

date = ['2016-02-23 09:36:26', '2016-02-24 10:00:32', '2016-02-24 11:28:22', '2016-02-24 11:27:20', '2016-02-24 11:24:15', '2016-02-24 11:20:25', '2016-02-24 11:17:43', '2016-02-24 11:12:03', '2016-02-24 11:09:11', '2016-02-24 11:08:44', '2016-02-24 11:05:28', '2016-02-24 11:03:23', '2016-02-24 10:58:08', '2016-02-24 10:53:59', '2016-02-24 10:49:34', '2016-02-24 10:43:33', '2016-02-24 10:35:27', '2016-02-24 10:31:50', '2016-02-24 10:31:17', '2016-02-24 10:30:05', '2016-02-24 10:29:21']
sec = [time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple()) for d in date]
mean = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(np.mean(sec))
print(mean)
```

Comment: I would do exactly as you suggested.

Comment: I agree with @ppaulojr. Convert them to units and average them.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681703/average-time-for-datetime-list

Comment: @ppaulojr I still feel that there should be some function in `pandas` or `numpy` to do the same job.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In NumPy all `datetime64[s]`s are internally represented by 8-byte integers.
The ints represent the number of seconds since the Epoch.

So you could convert the `date` list to a NumPy array of `datetime64[s]` dtype,
view it as dtype `i8` (8-byte ints), take the mean, and then convert the int back into a `datetime64[s]`.

---

```
import numpy as np

date = ['2016-02-23 09:36:26', '2016-02-24 10:00:32', '2016-02-24 11:28:22', '2016-02-24 11:27:20', '2016-02-24 11:24:15', '2016-02-24 11:20:25', '2016-02-24 11:17:43', '2016-02-24 11:12:03', '2016-02-24 11:09:11', '2016-02-24 11:08:44', '2016-02-24 11:05:28', '2016-02-24 11:03:23', '2016-02-24 10:58:08', '2016-02-24 10:53:59', '2016-02-24 10:49:34', '2016-02-24 10:43:33', '2016-02-24 10:35:27', '2016-02-24 10:31:50', '2016-02-24 10:31:17', '2016-02-24 10:30:05', '2016-02-24 10:29:21']

mean = (np.array(date, dtype='datetime64[s]')
        .view('i8')
        .mean()
        .astype('datetime64[s]'))

print(mean)
```

prints

```
2016-02-24T09:43:40-0500
```