# Pandas average timestamp for DateFrame subset

Tags: python, pandas

I am really new of Pandas and I have a problem how to calculate the average value of a set of time.

I have a csv file with columns: Date, Time, Outside temperature

I imported and modify it as:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./file.csv", parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).dt.time
```

I prefer to have the date and time separate in two different columns and not use them as index.

I already extracted the part I need and obtaining something like this:

```
           Date      Time  Outside Temperature
4343 2006-06-30  13:00:00                 15.9
4344 2006-06-30  13:10:00                 15.9
4345 2006-06-30  13:20:00                 15.9
4346 2006-06-30  13:30:00                 15.9
4347 2006-06-30  13:40:00                 15.9
```

as you can see at same temperature I have different time, I would like to have the average value of the time, something like: 13:22:34

How can I do it?

I checked other questions as: [Average time for datetime list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681703/average-time-for-datetime-list), I tried several way to access to the time, for example:

```
print(tempdf["Time"].dt.hour)
```

but I obtain the error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I think I make a mistake in the conversion to timestamp.

Do you have any suggestion?

I am using python3.5 and pandas 0.20.2

Thanks a lot

Ciccio

**Edit:**

The original csv file for the time has the format hh:mm without the seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `timedelata`s by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then convert to `ns`, get `mean` and convert back:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./file.csv", parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)

a = pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"] + ':00').mean()
print (a)
0 days 13:20:00
```

---

```
a = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"] + ':00').values.astype(np.int64).mean())
print (a)
0 days 13:20:00
```

If need average time for each unique dates:

```
df['td']= pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"] + ':00').values.astype(np.int64)
df1 = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('Date')['td'].mean()).reset_index()
print (df1)
        Date       td
0 2006-06-30 13:20:00
```

... or for unique temperature:

```
df['td']= pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"] + ':00').values.astype(np.int64)
df1 = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('Outside Temperature')['td'].mean()).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Outside Temperature       td
0                 15.9 13:20:00
```

...or mean of `temperature` and `time`s:

```
df['Time']= pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"]).values.astype(np.int64)
df1 = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).mean()
df1['Time']= pd.to_timedelta(df1["Time"])
print (df1)
        Date     Time  Outside Temperature
0 2006-06-30 13:20:00                 15.9
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I obtain this error:

TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: You cannot convert to times not to datetimes, because column date is converted in read_csv by `parse_date` parameter. And `type` of `time`  column need string.  I add to answer `read_csv`. Need remove `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).dt.time`

Comment: Yes sorry I saw later your other answer.
The problem is the csv file doesn't have seconds is in the format: hh:mm, and when I run it wants the format hh:mm:ss
Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Then need `df['td']= pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"] + ':00').values.astype(np.int64)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

**Preparing a sample dataframe (represents your subset):**

```
# Initiate dataframe
date_var = "date"
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', '2018-08-05 17:06:01'],
                        ['A', '2018-08-05 17:06:02'],
                        ['A', '2018-08-05 17:06:03'],
                        ['B', '2018-08-05 17:06:07'],
                        ['B', '2018-08-05 17:06:09'],
                        ['B', '2018-08-05 17:06:11']],
                  columns=['column', date_var])

# Convert date-column to proper pandas Datetime-values/pd.Timestamps
df[date_var] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_var])
```

**Extraction of the desired average Timestamp-value:**

```
# Extract the numeric value associated to each timestamp (epoch time)
# NOTE: this is being accomplished via accessing the .value - attribute of each Timestamp in the column
In:
[tsp.value for tsp in df[date_var]]
Out:
[
    1533488761000000000, 1533488762000000000, 1533488763000000000,
    1533488767000000000, 1533488769000000000, 1533488771000000000
]

# Use this to calculate the mean, then convert the result back to a timestamp
In:
pd.Timestamp(np.nanmean([tsp.value for tsp in df[date_var]]))
Out:
Timestamp('2018-08-05 17:06:05.500000')
```

Answer (score 0):

To take mean of time you convert time series to timedelta type and take mean. To get average of time and temperature for a perticular date use groupby

## edit

If Time column only contains hh:mm
you need to add secs in it

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"] + ':00')
print(df)
```

output:

```
         Date     Time  Outside Temperature
0  2006-06-30 13:00:00                 15.9
1  2006-06-30 13:10:00                 15.9
2  2006-06-30 13:20:00                 15.9
3  2006-06-30 13:30:00                 15.9
4  2006-06-30 13:40:00                 15.9
```

Convert Time to int so that it can be used in groupby

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype(int)
```

Group by date column and get mean of time and Outside Temperature

```
df = df.groupby(['Date'])['Time', 'Outside Temperature'].mean()
```

Now again convert time series to Timedelta type

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

Output:

```
               Time  Outside Temperature
Date                                    
2006-06-30 13:20:00                 15.9
```

Comment: What pandas version do you use?

Comment: @jezrael its 0.19.1 and python version 3.4.3. Installing newest version 0.20.1.

Comment: for me in `0.20.2` it does not work...I use windows and you?

Comment: @jezrael, just updated my pandas package to 0.20.2 it still works on that. Btw am using ubuntu.