# How to calculate the mean of dateTime.time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that has many rows and is in the below form. I am interested in calculating the mean value of hours. What should be the correct way to do in pandas? The datatype of the date and time column is in DateTime. Thanks in advance.

| arrivalDate | arrivalTime | dayOfWeek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | 13:55:00 | Thursday |
| 2020-01-16 | 14:01:00 | Thursday |
| 2020-01-02 | 14:02:00 | Thursday |

Comment: What does your code look like so far? (What have you tried?)

Comment: Take a look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681703/average-time-for-datetime-list.

Comment: in question show expected result.

Comment: Do you want just global average of `arrivalTime` or average `arrivalTime` per `dayOfWeek`, month, year, ...?